# Submission fails (UWP with Win 32 app crashes at start on Windows 10S)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, clr, wack

**Please See my Latest Update**

---

On the 22nd of June 2018, Microsoft informed me that my UWP App with a Win 32 backend cannot be tested due to it crashing at startup. After contacting the app certification team, they said it has been tested on two Windows 10S devices of which none successfully launches the app...

They suggested I contact support but I cannot dash out R1000 for a support engineer to help me change one or two things...

[image: The Certification Report]
[image: Part of the communication between me and the certification team]

I unfortunately do not have any logs to post or any furtherer details... What I don't get is that the app passes the WACK with flying colours, absolutely no errors. It also works perfectly on three Windows 10 Home Editions.

Please note that I built the app from the ground up. No Project Centennial or any conversions.

Has anybody encountered something similar? Have I missed some thread on the internet? Please help.

Thank you.

**Edit**

The app has a UWP UI and calls LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync() upon the `GridLoad` event of the UWP app to display NotifyIcons.

If any more information is required, please ask.

**Edit**

Could a `Debug.WriteLine` call (I forgot to remove it before packaging and submitting) or any of these namespaces cause an issue?

```
using Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Core.Preview;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
```

Sorry guys, I've never worked with Windows 10S before.

**Edit**
I asked Microsoft to only test it on Win 10 Home, etc. and they let me know that, even under 'normal' conditions, it crashes. I still do not have any logs. However, on my side it works on 3 Win 10 Home devices without issues.?

**Edit 06 July 2019**

Well, it has been an interesting 9 months...

Since this thread's last update, I have discovered how to deploy my app through the MS Store to certain people only. Great, I could then debug. When installing and running it through the Store, it crashed on the splash screen as MS reported. I could get reports through Event Viewer. Think it was MoAppHang and some .Net Exception (please read on before commenting)

Late last year (about October, sorry can't remember the exact date), I had to delete my user profile as it was corrupted. I then randomly repackaged the app, and uploaded it. It surprisingly worked on my test devices. So, I uploaded it for certification and it passed. All was well.

Fast forward to now. I need to update it. Actually, I have written the code and packaged it. Now I upload it using a package flight to the test devices. Behold, the invisible bug is back...

Please see Event Viewer reports and Visual Studio debugging screenshots on [this OneDrive link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiJUIHojyRd1-EJK8yL7ga_geFgy) . Please note, the files under Event Viewer do not correlate to the Visual Studio debugging run. Do these get stored somewhere else in Event Viewer? I also could not get a `.wer` file for the debugging session. You should be able to follow the debugging session according to the screenshots modify times.

What I did was open the solution with the source code in VS2019, but went to `Debug` -> `Other Debug Targets` -> `Debug Installed App Package`. I checked `Stop at first statement` (does this relate to the first statement in *MY* code? If it does, it is not my code that's buggy as it does not reach my code, or I am misunderstanding this function). Could this be a bug in the CLR? I have no C++ interop directly in my code. I have also included the debug log.

One thing to note is that I have changed my environment. I installed a new SSD and the May update of Win10. I have also changed my min version from 15063 to 16299 and my target to 18362. Could it be looking for some file that **is** present during launching (and debugging) from Visual Studio as well as Sideloading, but **not** when launching from the `Store`?

`Compile with .NET Native tool chain` is checked. Before I ran it from Visual Studio for the first time, I did delete the `bin` and `obj` folders. Can it have something to do with `Optimize Code` being checked?

One weird thing is that this app (Caps, Num + Scroll Lock Checker (Pro)) is somehow linked through the `MainPackageIdentityName` in the `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` to one of my other apps which is in development, but not at all publicly released; though, I have reserved the new app's name so long. Could this be a Dashboard related issue?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Youve not given any clue as to what your app does at start up, or even what your app does, relies on or anything.. how are we going to be able to help you with that?

Comment: Well, the app has a UWP UI and calls `LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync()` upon the `GridLoad` event of the UWP app to display NotifyIcons. Anything else ?

Comment: What is your app min version and target version? Can you try to follow the document to [Test your Windows app for Windows 10 in S mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s) to see whether you can get some log? Besides, Do you 
 CreateProcess/Process.Start an EXE that you’ve downloaded from a share or website in your code? Since in Windows 10 S mode, only Microsoft-signed code can run(OS binaries & apps from the Microsoft Store).

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply, 

My min version and target version both are 17134. I can't follow that document as I'm running Win 10 Home. And, I do not call any `Process.Start` methods anywhere...

Comment: @user9618595  In fact, if you plan to publish your app to the Microsoft Store, you must operate your app correctly on devices that run Windows 10 in S mode  this because it is a store requirement. You should test your app on devices that run Windows 10 in S mode to find the crash info and debug your app.